# azure log analytics delete

Tags: c#, azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there any way to perform delete operation on custom log entries in azure log analytics.I have followed this [link](https://dev.loganalytics.io/apiexplorer/query) for reference but only GET & POST methods are defined there.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, if you want to delete custom log in Azure log analytics, you can remove Custom Logs in Advanced Settings. Note: Custom Fields tied to that Custom Log will also be removed. For more details, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs#removing-a-custom-log).

Answer (score 0):

### Purging data

If you're looking for a way to purge data, [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/personal-data-mgmt#delete) will give you more information on how to do it.  Also, check out [this blog post](https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/30/azure-monitor-purge-azure-log-analytics-data-using-powershell/).  Keep in mind that this is a highly privileged operation.

---

### Custom Log based on files

To delete custom logs collected from text files, [see Hannahwy's link to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs#removing-a-custom-log)

---

### Custom Logs created via [HTTP Data Collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api)

#### Delete custom fields

If you're looking for way to delete custom fields, [this Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/custom-fields#viewing-custom-fields) shows a picture of it with the remove link next to the field.  This is under your Workspace:

- Choose Advanced Settings
- Navigate to Data > Custom Fields

#### Delete custom log

If you're looking to delete the entire custom log, I have **NOT** found a way to do it.  Since the feature is in public **preview**, I would expect that the ability will come in the near future.  When that happens, please leave a comment below.

Update:  [Please vote for the delete custom log feature here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/16434184-delete-custom-logs-sended-by-http-data-collector-a)